# Flask - Get clicked link info and pass it back to python file

Tags: python, html, flask, hyperlink, jinja2

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426137/flask-get-clicked-link-info-and-display-on-rendered-page) question on Stack Overflow that has a variation of the solution I am looking for. However, I am trying to run this inside a for loop like so:

```
{% for x in listOfCategories %}
   <h2><li><a href="{{url_for('links', type='{{x}}')}}">{{x}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in the app:

```
@app.route('/links', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def links():
    category = request.args.get('type')
```

The problem is that `type='{{x}}'` is inside quotation marks and so it is rendered as `{{x}}` literally, instead of the actual variable contents. Is there a way to escape the quotation marks in order to assign type to what is inside the `x` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `{{url_for('links', type=x)}}"` as everything between the double brace is interpreted as executable code - encasing that in another string will result in exactly what you saw.

Hence, the template should be

```
{% for x in listOfCategories %}
   <h2><li><a href="{{ url_for('links', type=x) }}">{{x}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!